# How to fix Wrong post request to '/' instead of '/login' in frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was sending a fetch post to '/login' route from my front end page but it always ends up sending a post to '/' in backend.

But if i use a form in my frontend it works fine.Only when using js to send a fetch post request this error occurs.

checked the network logger in  firefox even that confirms the fact that the post request some how is redirected to '/' instead of '/login'

please comment below for more details of the code this is the script i wrote in my frontend to send the post request the data contains the valid data.

```
        fetch('/login', {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            },
            method:'POST',

            body: {data}
        }).then(res => {

        });
```

some what like this

instead of this giving a post request to '/login' it gives to '/'.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what your problem is. If you're doing a fetch with /login then it'll be /login.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. All else being equal, this code won't do what you say it does.

Comment: there could be redirection implemented in backed if you don't pass valid credentials.